# zfs installation issue Ubuntu 12.04 on Amazon EC2

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.04, zfs

I attached Three EBS Volumes of 3GB to an Amazon EC2 Micro-instance and mounted the disks xvdd, xvdc and xvdb.

My aim was to create a zfs pool using these 3 disks.

I had updated, upgraded Ubuntu 12.04, installed the zfs-linux dependencies, added the zfs-native repo PPA  and then issued the zfs install command whhich is

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-zfs
```

After this, I get the console status which is as below **and after the "run-parts:" status indicated below, the install process never proceeded further**. I waited for 20+ minutes and got this:

```
Setting up zfs-dkms (0.6.0.91-0ubuntu1~precise1) ...
Loading new zfs-0.6.0.91 DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 3.2.0-31-virtual
Module build for the currently running kernel was skipped since the
kernel source for this kernel does not seem to be installed.
Setting up linux-headers-3.2.0-35 (3.2.0-35.55) ...
Setting up linux-headers-3.2.0-35-generic (3.2.0-35.55) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms 3.2.0-35-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-35-generic
```

Is this issue related to EC2 kernel for Ubuntu? or does the machine to run ZFS should be of higher capacity?

Comment: It should certainly build. Maybe something else wrong with the virtual machine?

Answer (score 0):

Usually with hosting providers the kernel is the case. My provider (ovh) delivers their own customized (and allegedly more secure) kernel (alas without sources), although reluctantly permits installing the generic kernel, which solved the problem for me. I don't know about Amazon - perhaps their customized kernel is crucial for their EC2 service. On the other hand I very much doubt any hosting provider would produce the source code of their kernel.